# button types in html

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I am new to html coding/javascript and the question is about button types. From w3schools website, there are three types of buttons

```
<button type="button|submit|reset">
```

- first question: why do we need `form` for `submit` button?

I notice that if the button is set to be `submit` but there is no form around it, http POST is not sent. It makes sense because it does not know what http message to send. But why do we need an extra layer of `form` instead of defining the action and http method inside button?

- second question: when would one use the `button`-type button?

[This w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp) gives examples to `submit` and `reset` buttons but not `button` buttons.

- third question: does `type` default to some value? or is it not required to have a type?

One code example I found on [this w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) has no type

```
`<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>`
```

Comment: ***w3schools is in no way affiliated with the W3C***, which has caused tremendous issues when their bad and dangerously incorrect documentation is regarded as "correct".

Comment: This a more seriuos place for HTML https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. why do we need form for submit button?

We do not need `form` for `submit` button, we need `submit` button for `form`.
The button submits form when clicked as well as `enter` in `text` field, but if you have only `radio`s, ticks and `textarea`s you have to make a button to be able to submit at all.

2. when would one use the button-type button?

The `type="button"` is *default* for `<button>` tag.
It goes from the `<input>` tag: if you write `<input type="button">`that will be the same as if you write `<button>`. So is for anothe `<input>` types: `<input type="submit">` and `<button type="submit"/>` are same (note that button *has* closing tag unlike input, so you may put HTML in it.).buttons.

3. does type default to some value? or is it not required to have a type?

see #2

Answer (score 2):

Answer to the first question:

The HTML element `<form>` is used to define a form that used to collect information from the user.
The form is what sends the information to another web page. So, the info can be processed.

For the second question:

It is good to use a simple button for a Javascript event. Such as the one you put in your question.

And finally the third question:

No, I don't think it has a default. But I would say if there was a default, I think it would be submit.

Answer (score 1):

usually *Forms* are used to send

#### data(like user information for login) and

#### files to back server(like `PHP`)

Example:

`<form method="POST" action="destination.php">
        <input type="text" value="EMail" name="email">
        <input type="submit" Value="OK">
</form>`

When user clicks on submit button ~> form sends inputed email to `destination.php` Securely because of **post** method.